# How to filter objects from object array in typescript

Tags: typescript

This is my object array. So I want to filter set of object from this and make another object array.

```
    employees = [
    {
        {
            name: "tom",
            age : 22,
            address: "moscow",
            gender: "male"
        },
        {
            name: "tom",
            age : 25,
            address: "manila",
            gender: "male"
        },
        {
            name: "tom",
            age : 21,
            address: "delhi",
            gender: "female"
        },
        {
            name: "tom",
            age : 20,
            address: "cydney",
            gender: "female"
        }
    }
    ]
```

For example: Think if I want to filter the employees who are belong to `male` category and make a new array named `male_employees`, then how i do this  thing.

```
    male_employees = [
    {
        {
            name: "tom",
            age : 22,
            address: "moscow",
            gender: "male"
        },
        {
            name: "tom",
            age : 25,
            address: "manila",
            gender: "male"
        }

    }
    ]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
male_employees_list = employees.filter(male_employee => male_employee.gender==="male")
```

Answer (score 1):

As someone commented, just have a look at the .filter() function, there are plenty of example on how to use it out there.

In your case something like this:

```
 male_employees = employees.filter(employee=>employee.gender==="male")
```